# Performant recording of performance (profiling) data

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, profiling

We have a fairly busy distributed cloud based system that we want to introduce basic profiling into.  Firstly we'd like to monitor web page render times and DB calls - we use EF and SQLServer.

The question is what is the best (performant & easy) way to record this information? My first thought is to store it in a DB, but would this cause a performance issue when a single page render may require multiple DB calls and hence, multiple inserts into the performance table.

Would it be better to store this information in memory only, or perhaps store in memory short term then batch persist to a DB later? Or is some other approach recommended?

Answer (score 0):

If you simply send `INSERT` statements to the database without block-waiting to receive values of identity columns, it should be fairly lightweight for the web server.

If the database table does not have any keys, (or only a clustered key,) it should be fairly lightweight on the server, too.

This would certainly be the easiest approach, and would not take much to implement it and give it a try, so I would recommend that you check whether it covers your needs before trying anything else.